# Cross compile my ROS package for Nvidia jetson TX2

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some ROS packages developed for a robot which I want to deploy on a [jetson **TX2**](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-tx2)(ARM® Cortex®-A57 MPCore) with **ROS melodic** (the robot has a TX2 for its computer). I want the packages to be compiled on a PC (running **Ubuntu 18** presumably) and deploy them on the TX2 to be run on it.

1. Basically I want the output of `catkin_make install` for TX2, in my PC so that I can put the `install/` directory into the robot from the build machine
2. I only need to cross compile my own packages. ROS and other dependencies will be pre installed on the TX2

I am an absolute noob to this cross compilation. The most straightforward guide I have found so far is [this article](https://medium.com/@tahsincankose/cross-compiling-ros-project-for-arm-263642b405ac) for raspberry pi. This [other article](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/drive-px2-ros-cross-compilation/60192) cross compiles ROS for PX2 but it is not very clear to me. Many other resources are outdated.

Can someone please show me the path I should follow for this?  Where do I begin? Which toolchains do I use? What options do I set (catkinm CMake...)? Any insight related to this is much appreciated

---

What I have found so far (Are these what I need? I have no idea)

1. [GCC toolchain for 64bit BSP](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=tool%20chain&tx=%7B2b6b6c93-9aa2-4bbf-8d15-8ed8e9568030%7Dproduct,jetson_tx2)
2. [TX2 is aarch64](https://elinux.org/Jetson_TX2)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357708/cross-compile-my-ros-package-for-nvidia-jetson-tx2/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2020-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2020-07-21**:
I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but what I ended up doing is setting up an arm emulator on my x86 host machine and run a docker container with ROS to compile my packages. It is almost as slow as compiling on target but works for what we need. I got the idea from here https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/#setting-up-arm-emulation-on-x86

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-29**:
Does [ros-tooling/cross_compile](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile) not cover this use-case?

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2020-07-29**:
@gvdhoom just came across that a few hours ago and it works pretty well. No hassle. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Until a good answer comes up, check the [thread I started in nvidia developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cross-compile-my-ros-package-for-nvidia-jetson-tx2/142926/10) if someone is stuck with a similar problem. I'm still halfway from getting everything right but got some stuff to work.

**EDIT:** No need to do it from the scratch. Use [ros-tooling/cross_compile](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile)

---

Originally posted by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) with karma: 168 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0